# android screenshot custom

Tags: android, screen

As the title,I want to take a screenshot and I want to clip the screen custom. For example ,I can draw a rectangle area and make a screenshot only in the rectangle area.
thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Hello You can Try to use This One google.code [Link](http://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/) Click here yet i have not test it but it will give some hint to you.and can Also Have to look in SO Question [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/screenshot-android) Click here

Comment: Thank you first,I have see your link before.But it does't what i want .I know how to make a full screenshot.I just want to make a screenshot only in the area which i custom.